# Scala Number type pattern matching

Tags: scala

I have a field of type Number, can someone tell me why the following code doesn't work and how to elegantly fix it.

```
val n:Number = 10.0
n match {
    case d:Double=>println(d)
}

error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type
```

Comment: You seem to be using `java.lang.Number`, while scala floating point literals are not subtypes of `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: Well, it works when I do this, n match {case d:Number if d.isInstanceOf[Double]=>println(d)}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala's `Double` is not the same as `java.lang.Double`, which is a sub-class of `java.lang.Number`, so it can never possibly match. It *can* if you match against `java.lang.Double`

```
val n: Number = 10.0

n match {
    case d: java.lang.Double => println(d)
    case _ => println("Not a Double")
}
```

I wouldn't say there is anything elegant about this, though, and it's hard to make any further suggestions without knowing what you want to do with it.

Comment: Concerning OP's comment, is there some conversion done for `isInstanceOf[Double]` that will make it return `true`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Autoboxing, I think. That is, `scala.Double` gets boxed to `java.lang.Double`.